# Multi-source single destination algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I have a graph where I need to find distances from multiple sources to single destination. I know how to find single source to multi destination using dijkstra's algorithm.

I found an accepted answer here: [Algorithm like Bellman-Ford, only for multiple start, single destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772855/algorithm-like-bellman-ford-only-for-multiple-start-single-destination)

But I don't understand why it will work. can anyone explain why this answer works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works because if you have an (original) source `s`, and your target `t` - in the modified graph, you reverse the edges and find a shortest path from `t` to all nodes, including to `s`.

This path is `t->v1->v2->...->vk->s`

Each edge (u,v) in this path exist if and only if there is an edge in the original graph `(v,u)`, so the above path in the reversed graph can be directly translated to a path:

```
s->vk->vk-1->...->v2->v1->t
```

The weight of the paths is identical, and there is no shorter path, otherwise - you would have found it on the reversed graph.

---

As a side note, I personally prefer to transform multiple source problem to single source problem by creating a new dummy node `x`, and create an edge from `x` to any of the sources with weight 0, and then run shortest path algorithm with `x` as the source.

(Assuming what you need is the shortest path from some source to the target)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the side note will help me a lot.